# Can I use an SDXC card in a Canon Eos 500D?

Tags: canon, sdxc

I'm new here. I bought this: SanDisk SDSDXN-128G-G46 Extreme (SDXC), but when I put in the camera, and try to format it, the camera system gives me an alert that it can't do it and to change the card.

Is there a compatibility problem between the 500D and the SDXC card models? If yes, can someone suggest an sd optimal for Raw photo of the same memory space (128g)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NOTE: I read a comment on Amazon of a user using this model on the eos 500D without a problem. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

The Canon EOS 500D only accepts **SD** and **SDHC** cards, which go up to **32GB**.

**SDXC** cards (which were only introduced in the same year the 500D was released) are not supported, so you're out of luck there.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Wasted my money on two sd cards that didnt work....what an expensive mistake!!! Thanks to this post I've now bought two sdhc and have a functioning camera again!